# Ubuntu 18.04 fail to recognize my second nvme ssd

Tags: dual-boot, ssd, nvme

I've just purchased a second NVMe SSD for my laptop(which has dual m.2 slots both support nvme), planning to install ubuntu 18.04 onto it alongside windows 10 (which is installed on the first ssd).

Before the installation, I've already made some changes to UEFI settings:

- change SATA mode from RST(RAID) to AHCI, and reconfigure ahci drivers on windows 10 so that it can boot
- turn off secure boot

**The new ssd works fine under windows 10, I can even run speed tests on it.** But after I used a USB drive to boot into ubuntu and opened `gparted`, the system fail to recognize it, only the original ssd and the thumbdrive itself is displayed. `fdisk -l` and `lsblk` gave me same results.

I did some research, checked out `dmesg | grep nvme` and found the following errors:

```
nvme1: failed to set apst feature (270)
nvme1: failed to create IO queue (270)
```

I've tried multiple linux distributions(all the latest version, linux kernel 4.15+), but is stuck with the same output. I followed [an article online](https://bugs.archlinux.org/task/57331) and changed kernel flags on startup, but the problem persists. Is there anything wrong with my settings, or there's some problem with my ssd?

**Added 2018/9/9**
The model I'm using is Lenovo Ideapad 720s 15IKB with a i5-7300HQ processor, 8Gigs of DDR4 RAM and PM961 256G ssd. The ssd I've bought myself is a Asgard 512G NVMe SSD([amazon link](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B074K47CCJ) I have no idea why it says it's a sata 3 solid state drive).

I've turned off fast boot in Windows 10. I can't find any firmware updates for my SSD.

Comment: Is Windows fast start up off? While not drive you want to install, gparted or installer want to scan all drives, and if fast start up is on, scan fails. http://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/ubuntu-16-showing-windows-10-partitions  Many SSD need firmware updates and often system needs UEFI update from vendor.  What brand/model system or motherboard. What video card/chip?